# How to convert string into string literal type in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

```
export interface LoadTodos {
  type: "LOAD_TODOS_ACTION"
}

export interface AddTodo {
  type: "ADD_TODO_ACTION",
  todo: Todo
}

export type KnownAction = LoadTodos| AddTodo;
```

currently I'm doing this:

```
  CallAction({ type: "LOAD_TODOS_ACTION" });
```

I want to do this:

```
CallAction("LOAD_TODOS_ACTION");
```

or ideally:

```
CallAction<LoadTodos>();
```

How should I implement CallAction? Is it even possible?

```
function CallAction<T extends KnownAction>()
{
   type P1 = T["type"];
 doSomethingWithAction({type:T.type}); // type property is an instance property so cannot be retrieved obviously

//or 

 type P1 = T["type"];
 doSomethingWithAction({type:P1}); // P1 is a type not string


    }
```

LoadTodos contains type: "LOAD_TODOS_ACTION" so there should be a way to get one from the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly then:

```
type ActionType = "LOAD_TODOS_ACTION" | "ADD_TODO_ACTION";

interface Action {
    type: ActionType;
}

interface LoadTodos extends Action {
    type: "LOAD_TODOS_ACTION"
}

interface AddTodo extends Action {
    type: "ADD_TODO_ACTION",
    todo: Todo
}

function CallAction(type: ActionType) {
    // whatever
}
```

Or:

```
function CallAction<T extends Action>(action: T) {
    // whatever
}
```